# MediaSource.isTypeSupported inconsistent result for mp3 on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, audio, microsoft-edge, html5-audio, media-source

I ran: `MediaSource.isTypeSupported("audio/mp3")` on the most recent Edge browser which returns **false**. This means that the user agent can not play this type according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/isTypeSupported). However, when I drag a mp3 file into the browser window, it will play.

Have anyone an idea why that is?

Comment: I agree with Brad's answer. You can refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) for MIME type of `.mp3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `audio/mp3` isn't the correct type.

You're looking for `audio/mpeg` instead.